# Conflict with jscrollPane and animate

Tags: jquery

I am using jscollPane on a div that is displayed via the jquery animate function.

The animate function seems to be causing a conflict with the jscrollpane script and thus the scrollbars do not show.

Here is an example page to demonstrate: http://mikesewell.net/dev/scrollpane/

The div #text is hidden using display: none;  it is shown using this function:

```
$(".bio-button").hover(function() {
        $(this).next("#text").animate({opacity: "show"}, "slow");
    }
```

If I dont' hide #text jscrollPane works fine, but if using this function to animate stops the scrollbars from showing.

Any suggestions would be greatly, greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
 $(this).next("#text").animate({opacity: "show"}, "slow");
```

Try this:

```
$('#text').fadeIn('slow');
```

There should only be one div with `id="text"` so there's no need to traverse the DOM to find it.

Also, per [JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate):

> Unlike shorthand animation methods such as .slideDown() and .fadeIn(),
>   the .animate() method does not make hidden elements visible as part of
>   the effect.

Comment: I tried using $('#text').fadeIn('slow');  but it still ended up with the same result.